# Get Facebook response implicitly in ASP.net application

Tags: asp.net, facebook

i am posting a comment on Facebook with the help 
of Asp.net application.

So,Is there any feature provided by Facebook
can i get implicitly ,viewer's are like this post through our Asp.net application.
(means Is facebook pinged our asp.net application instantly)

Please suggest me as a convenient ways.
reply will appreciate.

Thanks.
Rahul

Comment: Are you looking for a solution where facebook sends a notification to your application when a user has posted comment?

Comment: Don’t understand what info exactly you want – but sounds to me as if you are looking for realtime updates: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

Comment: Why do you post the exact same question under another user name just one hour after you already asked it? http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/15403466/facebook-implicitly-send-like-information-to-the-server